# Koroks on the map

Tags: zelda-wind-waker, zelda-wind-waker-hd

In Wind Waker HD, if you talk to the Deku Tree about the Island Koroks after finishing the Forbidden Forest dungeon, he will tell you that he has marked the Koroks on the map for you.

However, I don't see anything on the ocean map marking which squares the Koroks are on.  What exactly am I supposed to be looking for on the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently they appear as red leaves on the map... but are only present if you have Forest Water in your inventory.